# Why does my git interactive rebase change for the last commit message then show Everything up-to-date when I do a push?

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-push, git-interactive-rebase

I did a push of my latest changes

```
git push origin master
```

then I amended the commit message with an interactive rebase, i.e.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

and changed the message in the last commit.

This saved successfully, but when I did a `git push origin master` it just says `Everything up-to-date`.

Now the git history doesn't show the wording change as actually have been made?

However when I do a `git commit --amend -m"msg"` and then try and push the change is 'seen'.

Answer (score 2):

During the interactive rebase I had changed the commit message... but I hadn't changed the first column ('action') from `pick` to `reword` (or just `r` for short).

Doing this made the change get applied correctly.

Comment: As the description in the interactive-rebase to-do list (the file that is opened in your editor when you start the rebase) says, the messages in that file are only for illustrative/navigation purposes. All actual changes happen after you have saved the file.

Answer (score 0):

> then show Everything up-to-date when I do a push?

A possible explanation, illustrated with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018): during a "`rebase -i`" session, the code could give older timestamp to commits created by later "pick" than an earlier "`reword`", which has been corrected.

See [commit 12f7bab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12f7babd6b68b14012f8beed42d82688c7e8f04a) (18 Apr 2018) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0657e0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0657e0f802b0e0a97738c074dd27ee47eeb3366f), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `sequencer`: reset the committer date before commits
>
> Now that the sequencer commits without forking when the commit message
>   isn't edited all the commits that are picked have the same committer
>   date.
>   If a commit is reworded, it's committer date will be a later time
>   as it is created by running an separate instance of 'git commit'.
>
> If the reworded commit is follow by further picks, those later commits
>   will have an earlier committer date than the reworded one. This is
>   caused by git caching the default date used when `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` is
>   not set.
>   Reset the cached date before a commit is generated in-process.

Answer (score -1):

Because commit hash of the last commit doesn't change.
You have to change commit hash of the last commit, so the server will know you have made changes.

You can use reword or edit command when doing interactive rebase. Or just use commit --amend.

Comment: The reasoning is logical here, but there's something missing. Running `git commit --amend` does indeed change the hash of the most recent commit, but `git push` still shows `Everything up-to-date`.